# The minimal amount that can be paid?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In some country there are 12-, 20-, and 30-florin coins only. What is the minimal amount that can be paid if both sides have many coins of each type?

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to give change the least amount is $2$ florins. You pay that by paying $32=12+20$ florins and get $30$ back.

Obviously you can't pay anything less as every coin is a multiple of $2$ florins.